# Auto Fill Data Table With Email Id

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular-datatables

I am Using the https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-datatables angular-datables as soon as i login into the application the search bar auto fills with the email id as shown below in the image [Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GkmA.png)

i need to clear it each time in order to view the result

```html
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">
    <thead>

      <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Role</th>
    <th>Cloud Accounts</th>
    <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let ca of usersLists; let i = index">
      <td>{{ca.name}}</td>
      <td>{{ca.emailId}}</td>
      <td><span class="badge  badge-pill badge-primary">{{ca.roleType}}</span></td>
      <td><span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" (click)="show(ca)">{{ca.linkedCloundAccounts}}</span></td>
      <td>
          <ng-container *ngIf=" isActionEnabled ">
        <a (click)="editUserAccount(ca)" data-toggle="modal" dat Add Usera-target="#edit-user" class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-xs" title="Edit User"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>

        <a (click)="deleteUserAccount(ca,i)" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger btn-fill btn-xs" title="Delete User"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
        </ng-container>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

and this is my typescript code

```js
  @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
  dtElement: DataTableDirective;

  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

how can i disable that auto fill when the application executes.

Answer (score 0):

this one clears the search box:

```
this.dtOptions.oSearch = {"sSearch": ``}
```

this one does not save table options:

```
this.dtOptions.stateSave = false
```

Or your browser just simply remember your email, check other browser...

Comment: ERROR : Property 'oSearch' does not exist on type 'Settings'. Did you mean 'search'? , i tried with search option also but search bar is not clearing.

Comment: did you try another browser?

Comment: different browser is working fine. i cleared the auto fill data too.
still it auto fill the search box.

Comment: if it works fine in a different browser it means its not datatables related issue, dig into your browser